# Find out the Number of ways in which two queens intersects (won't be stable) on n*n chessboard?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures

I can do this using combinations.
Queens won't be *stable* (under attack) if they are in the same :

1. Vertical
2. Horizontal
3. Diagonal.

So

1. Its possible by : `n * P(n,2)` ways
2. Its possible by : `n * P(n,2)` ways
3. Its possible by : `2 * ( P(n,2) + P(n-1,2) + ... + P(2,2)) + 2 * (P(n-1,2) + ... + P(2,2))`

What would be an appropriate algo for the above ?

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n = 8;
        int arr[][] = new int[n][n];
        long x = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for (int  j=0;j<n;j++){

                x +=  Math.min(n-1-i, n-1-j) + Math.min(i, j) + Math.min(n-1-i,j) + Math.min(i,n-1-j);

                x+= 2*n -2;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(x);
     }
}
```

How about the above logic?

Comment: Don't spam tags. You want Java, not C. So don't tag as C.

Comment: @StoryTeller  C will also do, no issues. I need an approach or maybe pseudocode.

Comment: [Number of ways to place two nonattacking queens on an n X n board](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C44%2C140%2C340&language=english&go=Search)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 Queens on N x N board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601552/2-queens-on-n-x-n-board) — or at least related.

Comment: A simple close formula: `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(3*n-1)/6`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Above formula is not correct.
 For instance 3*3 chessboard has 56 ways in which two queens are   unstable.

Comment: @Ashish Kataria: I'm sorry, but there are only `8` ways to place 2 unattacked (stable) queens on `3*3` chess board: one queen in the corner (4 possibilities) and another queen on the opposite side (2 possibilities), so we have `4 * 2 == 8`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I need to find out only unstable possibilities

Comment: @AshishKataria There are 36 ways to put 2 queens on a 3*3 board. If only 8 of them are stable (unattacked), the others must be unstable (attacked).

Comment: Formula for unstable (attacking) queens is `n * (5 * n - 1) * (n - 1) / 3`

Answer (score 2):

Well, for `n * n` board there are

```
 All:      n * n * (n * n - 1) / 2
 Stable:   n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (3 * n - 1) / 6
 Unstable: n * (5 * n - 1) * (n - 1) / 3
```

positions. (See https://oeis.org/A036464 for details). Some examples for small `n`s:

```
 n   all   unstable   stable
-----------------------------  
 1     0 =        0  +     0
 2     6 =        6  +     0
 3    36 =       28  +     8
 4   120 =       76  +    44
 5   300 =      160  +   140
 6   630 =      290  +   340
 7  1176 =      476  +   700
 8  2016 =      728  +  1288
 9  3240 =     1056  +  2184
10  4950 =     1470  +  3480
```

The implementation (Java) is evident

```
private static long unstableCount(long n) {
  return n * (5 * n - 1) * (n - 1) / 3;
}
```

It may be interesting to note, that

```
 All      = O(n**4)
 Stable   = O(n**4)
 Unstable = O(n**3) // just cube
```

so for a large board almost all postions are stable.

If queens are *distinguishable* (e.g. you have *white* and *red* queens) all you have to do is to *multiply* the numbers and formulas above by `2` (swapping queens brings a new position now).

```
private static long unstableDistinguishableCount(long n) {
  return n * (5 * n - 1) * (n - 1) / 3 * 2;
}
```

**Edit**: Naive sampling implementation (we loop over all possible queens' positions) could be

```
private static long unstableCountNaive(int n) {
  long result = 0;

  for (int file1 = 0; file1 < n; ++file1)
    for (int rank1 = 0; rank1 < n; ++rank1)
      for (int file2 = file1; file2 < n; ++file2)
        for (int rank2 = file1 == file2 ? rank1 + 1 : 0; rank2 < n; ++rank2)
          if ((file1 == file2) ||                  // Same file 
              (rank1 == rank2) ||                  // Same rank
              (file1 + rank1 == file2 + rank2) ||  // Same top-left bottom-right diagonal
              (file1 - rank1 == file2 - rank2))    // Same bottom-left top-right diagonal
            result += 1;

  return result;
}
```

**Edit 2**: if I got your idea right, you can just count diagonal attacks and then use symmetry:

```
private static long unstableCountBetter(int n) {
  long result = 0;

  // Attacked by top-left bottom-right diagonal 
  for (int rank = 0; rank < n; ++rank)
    for (int file = 0; file < n; ++file)
      result +=
        (rank + file >= n ? 2 * n - 2 - (rank + file) : rank + file);

  result = 
    // symmetry: we have TWO diagonals
    result * 2 +       
    // At each postion (n * n of them) we have n - 1 checks on the same rank
    n * n * (n - 1) +
    // At each postion (n * n of them) we have n - 1 checks on the same file
    n * n * (n - 1);

  // /2 if queens are indistiguished (728 for 8x8 board)
  return result / 2;
}
```

Comment: that's great, formula is pretty good and correct. Would be helpful if you elaborate more, framing of this formula. Can we also solve this using 2D array and for loops? Would help me to understand in depth. Thanks

Comment: @Ashish Kataria: as you can see, the asymptotic even for the unstable case is quite bad - *cubic* (the naive implementation - testing all queen's positions without *pruning* is even worth - `O(n**4)`). That's why any `for` loop implementation will not do even for small `n`s (`1000**3 == 1e9`) and thus, IMHO, should not be implemented.

Comment: @Ashish Kataria: try elaborate the formula yourself: it's not *that* difficult. Start with the easiest case, *All*. Can you see why it's `n * n * (n * n - 1) / 2`? Continue with *rooks* instead of queen - can you elaborate https://oeis.org/A035287 ? Investigate bishop case: how many diagonal `n*n` board has? How many checks each diagonal has? Sample bishops over, say, left-top to right-bottom diagonals. On both kind of diagonal. Do you have https://oeis.org/A172123 formula? Then combine your soultion into queens case.

Comment: Thanks, let me try..I edited the above question  with 1 solution of for loops, How about that logic? can you please see?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit incomplete but looking at the comments, I think I have got all the information to answer the question.

Since you wrote that there is 56 ways for 2 queens to intersect on a 3*3 board, you treat both queens as different, ie. ordered. eg. These 2 boards are different:

```
..q     ..Q
.Q.     .q.
...     ...
```

So, the answer to your question is simple formula for n*n board:

```
(n*n) * (n*n - 1) - n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(3*n-1)/3
```